# Unity3d - Hosting on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with hosting my Unity3d web application on GAE.
When the application loads and the web player starts to request the **".unity3d" file**, i use the following python script to make the HTTP response:

```
class UnityHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'WebPlayer.unity3d'

path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication (
    [('/(.*html)?', MainHandler), 
    ('/(.*unity3d)?', UnityHandler)
    ], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)
```

It doesn't work quite well, it finds the file but the Unity web player give me a "bad file length" error.

So can anyone tell me where the problem is ?
I think it has something to do with setting the "Content-type", but i don know how to fix it ?

Thanks,

Samer Samy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume, first, that you meant to indent the 3 lines starting with `path =`.

Second, I'm guessing your intent was to route the url "/" to WebPlayer.unity3d. However, both of your regexes will match the / since everything after the slash is optional; MainHandler will receive the request since it's first.

Third, it looks like you're trying to serve static files not only through a dynamic handler but also through a templating engine. Why? If you're just trying to serve static files verbatim, use [static handlers](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers).

Assuming you have placed your .unity3d files in a directory named static:

```
# render WebPlayer.unity3d on /
- url: /
  static_files: static/WebPlayer.unity3d
  upload: static/WebPlayer.unity3d

# match other .unity3d files
- url: /(.*\.unity3d)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.unity3d)

# match *.html and anything else
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work and i used something like this: 
`handlers:
# match .unity3d files
- url: /(static/webplayer.unity3d)
  static_files: static/webplayer.unity3d
  upload: static/webplayer.unity3d
  mime_type: application/vnd.unity`